# Filtering view by content author OR referenced field

Tags: views, 8

I have a user that is author and is referenced on a certain content type, I want to be able to filter a view to show all nodes where the user is referenced, example field_user and where the user is the author.

I can have access to the current user from my view and I did had a group with the OR operator so it can be filter to content author and from referenced field.

When I do things separately both work, I mean, I can get the nodes where the user is author and then I can get the nodes where he is referenced but when I add the two filters simultaneously with the OR operand this does not work, any idea?

In the image below are my settings to the view, I think that you may understand what I am doing.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one answered and I couldn't find a way to solve this trhough UI, I used views_pre_render hook to solve my problem.

You can see the solution I found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/239111/73238).