# Hide view results with hook

Tags: views, 8

I am trying to not show a certain view result using **hook_views_pre_render** but I didn't find the correct way to not display the result.

I did manage to have access to the view and change each result title to a test title, code:

```
function MODULENAME_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {

  if($view->id() == 'tasks') {
    foreach($view->result as $task) {
      $task->_entity->set('title', 'test - ' . time());
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use something like **$task->show = false;**, is there any way?

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to filter out those results in the first place? That way you won't get odd looking results if you use a pager for example

Comment: How can I filter the results programmatically ? I tried to filter the results through ui in view but couldn't get the results I want. 
I want to filter a content type results by author (to the logged user) and by field_user (that is a referenced user in content type). When I filter by author all works and even when I filter by field_user but when I apply a OR condition to show both.. only results that reference the user appear.. And I can't understand why that happens.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238820/filtering-view-by-content-author-or-referenced-field
I did ask, No answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem with the following:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if($view->id() == 'tasks') {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($view->result as $value) {
      if($i == 2)
        unset($view->result[$i]);
      $i++;
    }
  }
 }
```

The code above does not show the 3rd result from the view results. Add logic as you need.

Comment: Use the right hook does the trick for me :) (pre_render and not preprocess_views_view).