# How do I modify the result?

Tags: views, 8

Having an issue with HOOK_views_pre_render and HOOK_views_post_render, trying to alter the rendered output of the view. There are similar questions like: [Hide view results with hook](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239023/hide-view-results-with-hook) but I am not seeing the results as I am expecting under $view['result']

There is what looks like a full entity and not the markup that I'm expecting.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to modify?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to modify the views result row. Specifically a field and was exploring the different views hooks as I've used them many times in D7 and expected to see an array of rows in markup.

Comment: In my case, the solution that worked was to use the HOOK_preprocess_views_view_field, but during my research, I found links like the one I posted in the question that don't seem to work any longer. I just was not able to see how we would change the views markup in pre or post render hooks other then delete a result row.

How do you interact to set/change values in a views ResultRow object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HOOK_views_post_execute() and cycle through the results rows,  updating the row with something like:

```
        foreach ($viewExecutable->result as $key => $rr) {
          $title = $rr->_entity->getTitle();
          // update $title value...
          $viewExecutable->result[$key]->_entity->set('title', [['value' => $title]]);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks very much @jons for the answer. I was getting a PHP error that was causing a white screen of death - Call to undefined method Drupal\\taxonomy\\Entity\\Term::getTitle()  which is odd since the title is on a node and not a taxonomy. It was not always throwing this error though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jons, your answer allowed me to move further and I was able to set other fields in the view result now:

```
// Testing how we can update view result title value
$title = 'This is a custom title';
$newurl = 'http://www.nextide.ca';
$view->result[$key]->_entity->set('title', $title);
$view->result[$key]->_entity->set('body', 'This is a custom content');
$view->result[$key]->_entity->set('field_coned_site_course_url', $newurl);
```